# map of member functions of heterogenous types

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a map of heterogeneous function pointers and have mimicked that in a smaller program which has functions to either take a "int" or a "double" val.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/any.hpp>
    #include <map>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    class Functions
    {
    public:
        void intF(int f) { cout << " Value int : " << f << endl; }
        void doubleF(double f) { cout << " Value double : " << f << endl; }
    };

    const boost::any convertInt(const string& s)
    {
        cout << " string passed : " << s << endl;
        std::istringstream x(s);
        int i;
        x >> i;
        cout << " Int val : " << i << endl;
        return i;
    }

    const boost::any convertDouble(const string& s)
    {
        cout << " string passed : " << s << endl;
        std::istringstream x(s);
        double i;
        x >> i;
        cout << " Double val : " << i << endl;
        return i;
    }

    typedef void (Functions::*callFunc)( const boost::any);

    typedef const boost::any (*convertFunc)( const string&);

    struct FuncSpec
    {
        convertFunc _conv;
        callFunc _call;
    };

FuncSpec funcSpec[] = {
    { &convertInt, (callFunc)&Functions::intF },
    { &convertDouble, (callFunc)&Functions::doubleF },
};

int main()
{
    string s1("1");
    string s2("1.12");

    callFunc c = funcSpec[0]._call;
    convertFunc co = funcSpec[0]._conv;

    Functions F;
    (F.*c)(((*co)(s1)));

    c = funcSpec[1]._call;
    co = funcSpec[1]._conv;

    (F.*c)(((*co)(s2)));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I see the double value getting printed correctly but the int value is garbled. Could someone help me with this? Also is there a better way to achieve this functionality. In my program I have 2 functions - one taking a `vector<int>` and the other taking a `vector<double>`. I have to read the data from a file and call the appropriate setters in the object of the class which has these 2 functions.

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior. To the extent it appears to work, it only does so by accident. In particular, casts like `(callFunc)&Functions::intF` are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a member function to a different type like you are doing isn't valid.  Try this instead:

```
class Functions
{
  public:
    void intF(boost::any input)
    {
      int f = boost::any_cast<int>(input);
      cout << " Value int : " << f << endl;
    }

    void doubleF(boost::any input)
    {
      double f = boost::any_cast<double>(input);
      cout << " Value double : " << f << endl;
    }
};

.
.
.

FuncSpec funcSpec[] = {
  { &convertInt, &Functions::intF },
  { &convertDouble, &Functions::doubleF },
};
```

Comment: I rewrote my code to allow for handling for this scenario. It works but I am wondering if it is possible to make it more generic

Comment: @deepaktj: Generic to handle more types than int and double?  You could make the functions into templates to avoid repeating the conversion and printing code for each type, but you will still have to specify which types you are interested in.